# Calculate time when commands are received at server

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to find the time delay of commands which are sent over SSH.

I mean the difference between the time that command is sent from client with the time it's received by server. Is there any way to calculate it?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach I can think of is

```
$ date; ssh user@server date
Fri May  2 13:45:28 EEST 2014
Fri May  2 13:45:30 EEST 2014
```

The first `date` will print out the current date/time of your system. The second will connect to your server over ssh (`ssh user@server`) and run the `date` command on the server. Assuming that both client and server are synchronized to the same NTP server and so have the same time, that will let you see the time difference. Note that this won't be 100% accurate since there will be a tiny delay caused by the launching of the `ssh` command but we're talking about milliseconds so I doubt it will make a difference.

If you need greater precision, use something like this which will show the nanoseconds:

```
$ date +%T:%N; ssh user@server date +%T:%N
13:47:21:739912080
13:47:23:774238647
```

You can also use the verbose flag for `ssh` (`-v`) which will report the transfer speed. This only takes into account the time *after* the connection has been established and not the overhead needed for connecting in the first place:

```
$ ssh -v user@server exit 2>&1 | grep second
Transferred: sent 3272, received 1920 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6556.2, received 3847.1
```

The command above connects to the server and simply runs `exit` to quit the connection again. `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard output which allows us to `grep` for "second" and get the stats.